# Feature panel hover changer effect

Tags: jquery

Haven't seen this before so hopefully someone has a easy solve, I have a 3 feature panel divs side by side, what I want happen is the 1st panel has a "hover" class added so I can change the background etc and then on a timed interval the hover class jumps to the next panel then the next panel then back to the start on a loop.

Also on a side note can you keep the code in mind to be able to add more then 3 feature divs so you could have for example 6 or more or less etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### *[jsBin demo](http://jsbin.com/umegej/2/edit)*

```
var box=$('.box'), c=0;
function loop(){
   box.removeClass('active').eq(c++%box.length).addClass('active');
}loop();
setInterval(loop, 1000);
```

You can add *boxes* at whish!

**EDIT: stop loop on hover and continue from last hovered**

### *[jsBin demo 2](http://jsbin.com/umegej/6/edit)*

```
var box=$('.box'), c=0, int;
function tglClass(){   
   box.removeClass('active').eq(c++%box.length).addClass('active');
}
function loop(){
   int=setInterval(tglClass,1000);
}loop();
box.on('mouseenter mouseleave',function(e){
   c=$(this).index();  
   var evt=e.type=='mouseenter' ? (tglClass())(clearInterval(int)) : loop();
});
```

In this solution you don't even need the CSS `:hover` state!

Comment: I like this concept also, it includes a hover state, i'm probably asking to much but can the hover state disable the animation and then start again on mouse off?

Comment: @webmonkey237 I've updated my solution in order to permit this. You can try and mix Roko's with mine.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a simple implementation: http://jsfiddle.net/joplomacedo/j4Abt/

**EDIT:** *Solution updated to allow animation to be disabled on mouseover, and enabled on mouseleave.*

```
    var timeout,
        els = $('.box').children(),
        el = els.first().addClass('active'),
        el0 = el,

        startCycle = function () {
            function f() {
                el.removeClass('active');
                el = el.next().length ? el.next() : el0;
                el.addClass('active');
                timeout = setTimeout(f, 3000);
            }

            timeout = setTimeout(f, 3000);
        };

    els.on({
        mouseover: function (e) {
            var tg = $(e.target);
            if ( !tg.hasClass('active') ) {
                el.removeClass('active');
                el = tg.addClass('active');
            }
            clearTimeout(timeout);
        },
        mouseleave: function () {
            startCycle();
        }
    });

    startCycle();
```

Answer (score 0):

What about something like:

```
function jump($container, timeout) {
    var $current = $('.active', $container);
    var $next = $current.next();

    $('.active', $container).removeClass('active');

    if ($next.length) {
        $next.addClass('active');
    } else {
        $('.panel', $container).first().addClass('active');
    }

    setTimeout(function() {
        jump($container, timeout);
    }, timeout);
}

(function($) {
    var timeout = 1000;
    $('.slider-container').each(function() {
        var $container = $(this);
        setTimeout(function() {
            jump($container, timeout);
        }, timeout);
    });
})(jQuery);​
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/KgYDu/